# Script is not writing to HTML

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code, I'm new to JS so it's probably a simple problem.

```js
var x = "Hello"
var y = "Hi"
var z = "Hola"
var n = Math.random();
if (n < .33333) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + x + "</h1>");
}
elseif(n < .6666666) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + y + "</h1>");
}
else {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + z + "</h1>");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `elseif` is next to each other which shouldnot be the case.

```js
var x = "Hello"
var y = "Hi"
var z = "Hola"
var n = Math.random();
if (n < .33333) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + x + "</h1>");
}
else if(n < .6666666) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + y + "</h1>");
}
else {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + z + "</h1>");
}
```

Also when you write code do make sure you format it correctly, this will help you a lot with spotting these types of mistakes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, also if you work with JS more often I would suggest a IDE such as visual studio code. This makes it more easy to spot these kinds of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try `else if` not `elseif`:

```js
var x ="Hello";
var y = "Hi";
var z = "Hola";
var n = Math.random();
if(n < 0.33333) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + x + '</h1>');
}
else if(n < 0.6666666) {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + y + '</h1>');
}
else {
  document.write('<h1 style="text-align:center;">' + z + '</h1>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**else if** should be 2 separate words. You have them as one word **elseif** in your code on the 6th line in the snippet you provided.

Also, always remember what Martin Golding <sub>(apparently)</sub> said in 1994 - "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Programming style is very important. And there is no excuse to not formatting or styling your code which is easily readable to yourself, and more importantly others.